Bibliography in table of contents using biblatex
i am using bib latex and i try to include bibliography in the table of contents. I use \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] it seems to work but it prints the title of my bibliography chapter "Bibliography" in English. I want it to be in Greek so i use  \printbibliography[title={\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}]. If i use \printbibliography[title={heading=bibintoc,title={\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}] i get an error. "Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition"
My article is in Greek and the names of the chapters too, but the content of the bibliography is in English.
This is my preamble and the main body of my article.
Thank you
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{pstricks,graphics,color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,bibencoding=auto,language=autobib,uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{phdbib.bib}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont={small,bf}}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\setlength{\parindent}{6ex}
\linespread{1.15}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}



\input{Chapters/Titlepage}      
    
\include{Chapters/Abstract_Acknowledgement} 

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
    
    
    
    
\include{Chapters/Introduction} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter3} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter5} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter6} 
    
\selectlanguage{english}
\nocite{*}





\printbibliography[title={\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}]

\include{Chapters/Appendix} 
    
    
    
    
    
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

not necessarily the problem, but you should clean up your preamble to avoid issues generally. I'd also suggest passing languages as class rather than package options. how recent is your TeX install?

I don't think i know what you mean as passing class for the language option. By cleaning up the preamble you mean removing packages. If so i think i need all of them. Of course i maybe wrong, but thanks for your answer. I updated my tex installation about 2 weeks ago

\printbibliography[title={heading=bibintoc,title={\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}]  looks wrong and should most likely be \printbibliography[title={\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}, heading=bibintoc,]. Apart from that it is hard to say anything, since we cannot compile the shown code as we do not have the files you \include and your .bib file.
